# Preventing orphaned sql queries from website

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

We have a website that's having performance issues with stored procedure executions as the bottleneck.  One of the causes for this is that some of these stored procedures are kicked off on page load.

So lets say DB load is high and a user gets frustrated with how long a report on the page is taking to load, and repeatedly refreshes the page, kicking off new executions of the same stored procedure.

Here's the code we're using to execute the stored procedure and manage the connection:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(qry, CommandType.StoredProcedure, args))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapt.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
```

The old executions are still hitting the database even when the user leaves the page or refreshes it, spawning a new one.

**Two possible solutions:**

- Somehow kill the execution of the stored procedure when the user who spawned it leaves the page that it would have been shown on.
- Go a step further and try to persist the same instance of the connection so that if the user hits the same page it will wait for the results from the previous stored procedure and then display those on the page.

What are common practices as these things go, and how are they implemented?  How can I at least kill the stored procedure when a user leaves the page that called it?

Comment: How do you detect the user left? You would need some sort of cancellation token sent to asp.net to handle

Comment: If you can't fix the performance of the reports, consider a queue or similar system.  If you really need to detect disconnections you could consider a signalr type scenario where you check if the user is still alive before executing the long-running report task from the queue.

Comment: @JoePhillips I don't know.  I'm new to front end work so I consider that part of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Async Actions with cancellation tokens.

---

**MVC action method itself:**

```
[AsyncTimeout(600000)] // Necessary to avoid the too-short 45 second default timeout 
                       // (which also results in successful cancellation of the sql command 
                       // by the way in case that's something you want)
[Route("my-report")]
public async Task<string> MyReport(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
    // These two lines are a workaround - necessary for page refreshes to trigger cancellation in MVC 5
    CancellationToken disconnectedToken = Response.ClientDisconnectedToken;
    var token = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, disconnectedToken).Token;

    // get the data
    var response = await dbService.ExecDataSetProcAsync("stored_proc_name", cancellation token, storedProcedureArguments);

    // returning the page with whatever data
    return response;
}
```

**Stored procedure execution and cancellation logic:**
(I'm excluding the logic for building the SQLCommand in CreateCommand() to keep this example concise)

```
public async Task<DataSet> ExecDataSetProcAsync(string qry, CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] args)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(qry, CommandType.StoredProcedure, args))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    cancellationToken.Register(() => cmd.Cancel());

                    try
                    {
                        adapt.Fill(ds);
                    }
                    catch (SqlException e)
                    {
                        // Canceling the sqlCommand causes an exception.  This is a workaround 
                        // to catch it, in case you don't want to be throwing the exception.
                        if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            throw e;
                        }
                    }
                });

                return ds;
            }
        }
```